# Balancing teams according to Elo rating

Tags: java, arrays, game-engine

I was wondering how you would go about creating a balancing system for a game based upon the Elo system.

I've read a couple of posts on here regarding a similar system. I do the balancing system based upon sorting a list and then assigning odd players to one team and even to the other.

The problem I've found is that sometimes if I do a list like that and there is a massive gap in player Elo rating. The teams are somewhat unbalanced.

Example:

A list sorted as 1700,1500,1500,1300,1300,1400,1400,1400,1200,1200

The teams would look like

- Team 1: 1700,1500,1300,1400,1200
- Team 2: 1500,1300,1400,1400,1200

The averages would come out to an unbalanced team.

I'm not too sure on how you would make a better balancing system. I can provide what I have written down so far but it's not much. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something to consider is that Elo is not a linear scale, making averages somewhat less meaningful.

Answer (score 6):

Your question has the following two parts:

**Rating Problem**
You need to use a rating system which takes care of rating each player playing as part of the team.
Microsoft Research has created a [TrueSkill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueSkill) system for the same which is an improved version of Elo Rating for multiplayer games.

The page also talks about it being an improved version of [Glicko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glicko_rating_system) rating system. This is widely used in online chess forums as well.

**Team Formation**

You have a sorted list and you want to create two teams that are balanced (in terms of total rating). You need to look at [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). You leverage Dynamic Programming Solution which is pseudo-polynomial in time.

Comment: Was going to suggest TrueSkill too :)